# Need help on how to remove dresser drawers!

Tags: drawers

I am trying to remove my dresser drawers. There is a track on the side of the drawers with levers that go up on one side and down on the other. I have pulled the drawer all the way out and pushed the levers as far as they go, but the drawer still doesn't come out. I have tried jiggling and lifting as well, but no luck. Is there another step that I am overlooking? All the online videos show them sliding straight out![image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It's tough to answer something like this without more information. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 1):

Left side up, right side down; tug reasonably hard. The drawer should pop right out.

Comment: Yes, and be sure to not pull until the levers are depressed. You don't want to bind them and prevent them from disengaging. To clarify a bit, the slides are the same hardware on each side. The levers are reversed because the slides are mounted in opposing orientations.

Comment: Thank you!! I finally got them. You did have to push/pull the levers, but then pull the drawer out slightly, push the levers down until you heard another click, and then they came free! Thank you for helping me with what should have been a super simple task. It was weighing on me as the last item on my to-do list!